# How to solve the problem of pop-up windows when installing and upgrading software？

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading to Ubuntu22.04, some pop-up windows will appear when upgrading or installing software, requiring restarting and selecting configuration files. How can I solve these problems? I need to install and upgrade software automatically, and it must be completed in a completely non-interactive manner. Among the problems that arise during the upgrade, you need to choose to update or retain the original configuration file. During the upgrade and installation process, some services must be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure APT to answer those questions automatically. `apt-get` knows the following options:

- `--yes` -> answer questions automatically with "yes". However, in certain situations " yes" will not automatically be applied but the questions is still raised, e.g. when an essential package should be removed.
- `--assume-no` -> answer questions automatically with "no"
- `--force-yes`-> any questions is answered with "yes" under any circumstances

Especially the last option `--force-yes` can be dangerous, as it may lead to a broken system if the worst comes to the worse.

The [man page of apt-get](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html) holds more details on each option, I would recommend to study the man page before making changes to the configuration of apt-get.